# If statement to json value

Tags: objective-c

I´m trying to do an If statement from my viewcontroller to my weathercondition.m in which the web service is gathering weather information. It picks up the json from openweathermap API and shows the correct temperature in my app. However I would like to do an If statement to the temperature - like if it´s below 10 Celcius - a label can write out: "It is cold".

When I do this: newsCondition is from weathercondition.m

```
     if (newsCondition.temperature.floatValue == 0) {
         [label1 setText:@"It´s really cold today!"];
```

The label shows in the app but says "It´s really cold today" even though the temperature isn´t zero. Does anyone know how to write the If statement to compare it to the number parsed from the json?

Comment: put a break point and see what the value of newsCondition.temperature.floatValue is.

Comment: Btw: this is totally unrelated to JSON, as you already got the correct data

Answer (score 2, accepted):

"`floatValue`" isn't a property.

Why not change your code to something like:

```
if ([newsCondition.temperature floatValue] <= 0.0f)
{
    [label1 setText:@"it's really cold today!"];
} 
else
{
    [label1 setText:@""];
}
```

You'll also see I set the label to be blank if the temperature is greater than 0.  That's because table view cells (which is what I suspect you are using here) get recycled when old ones scroll out of view.

Comment: `[newsCondition.temperature floatValue]` and `newsCondition.temperature.floatValue` are syntactically equivalent.   (You're correct about the cell reuse issue.)

Comment: Is there documentation on being able to use "`.floatValue`" like a property, @AaronBrager?  It would be handy, but unless it's official I don't know if I would trust a pseudo-"getter" to always work.

Comment: Dot notation and declared properties are unrelated.  There was a recent discussion on the objc-language mailing list: http://lists.apple.com/archives/objc-language/2013/Nov/msg00007.html.  (Anyway, this discussion is off-topic for this question.)

Comment: Thanks! Simpel solution!